# What are alternatives to hard coding frames of views in iOS

Tags: ios, layout, resize, landscape-portrait

So the problem here is I need a totally different layout in landscape and portrait. For instance, I have a view that in portrait is on top but in landscape is on right of the screen.

I am currently using hard coded frames and I will change views' frames in "viewWillLayoutSubviews" but I don't like this hard coding, is there any way to achieve the same thing in Interface Builder ?

Thanks,

Comment: Well the ordering of the views are different in portrait and landscape, can I define different ordering in landscape and portrait with AutoLayout?

Comment: For instance, one of my views in portrait is 25 pixels away from top of the screen but in landscape should be 50 away from the right and should be vertically center.

Answer (score 1):

Try implementing `updateViewConstraints` to first `removeConstraints` then `addConstraints` for either portrait or landscape depending on the orientation.

Comment: Still I have to hard code constraints, right? It's the same thing but a bit cleaner cause I set the constraints and no more code. but still those constraints must be defined somewhere in the code.